# Output Text Formatted and Secure in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**I'd like to output text ($post->content) to the user including line breaks and urls.**

- If I would use `{{ $post->content }}`, line breaks won't be displayed and a
  converted URL looks like this `<a href="www.google.com'>www.google.com</a>` in the output.
- If I would use `{!! $post->content !!}`, line breaks and urls would be displayed correctly, but this would mean an actual security risk because a user could enter HTML or other code.

What would be the best way to handle my problem?

Comment: So the user is able to use the tags <br> and <a> but that's it? Not sure what you're asking here. You want HTML tags but only certain ones?

Comment: The user shouldn't use any tags at all. However, when I output the content by for example {{ nl2br($post->content) }} it won't work. The <a> tag is ist not entered by the user, it's generated by the linkConverter.

Comment: Consider something like HTML Purifier for this. There's [a Laravel package](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier).